# Passing a value from Visualforce Page to Controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller

How to pass a value from VF page to Apex Controller?
I need to have a hidden field with pre-populated value inside VF page.
Apex Controller must be able to read this value.
How to do that?

EDIT:

By saying "a hidden field", I did not mean the actual field on the Salesforce object but instead just some kind of value holder which could be accessed and read from the Controller. That value will be hard-coded in the VF page.

Comment: Did you search the community before posting the question ? I think this question is already answered here (http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24666/how-to-pass-javascript-value-to-controller) and probably is going to be marked as duplicate.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way I've found to do this is using `window.setTimeout()` with an abitrary low `delay` value which calls an `apex:actionFunction` that rerenders a dummy `apex:outputPanel` within an `apex:actionRegion`.

```
<script>
    window.setTimeout(function() { setParams("param1Value", "param2Value"); }, 1);
</script>

<apex:actionRegion>
    <apex:actionFunction action="{!setParams}" name="setParams" rerender="dummy">
        <apex:param name="param1" assignTo="{!param1}" value="" />
        <apex:param name="param2" assignTo="{!param2}" value="" />
    </apex:actionFunction>
    <apex:outputPanel id="dummy"/>
</apex:actionRegion>
```

The `apex:actionRegion` and the dummy `apex:outputPanel` prevent the whole page refreshing when the `apex:actionFunction` is called which will result in your JavaScript being called everytime and ending up in a refresh loop.

The `apex:actionRegion` also prevents the following error occurring when this is used on a page with an `apex:inputFile` component.

> `apex:inputFile` can not be used in conjunction with an action component, `apex:commandButton` or `apex:commandLink` that specifies a `rerender` or `oncomplete` attribute

Your controller will looks something like this:

```
public class ParameterPageController
{
    public String param1 { get; set; }
    public String param2 { get; set; }

    public PageReference setParams()
    {
        return null;
    }
}
```

---

**Edit:**
You don't actually need the `window.setTimeout()` call at all and can simply call your `apex:actionFunction` directly, however you **must** put your call to your `apex:actionFunction` **after** (although not necessarily directly after) it's declaration for this to work.

```
<apex:actionRegion>
    <apex:actionFunction ... >
        ...
    </apex:actionFunction>
    ..
</apex:actionRegion>

 |
 |
 |

<script>
    setParams("param1Value", "param2Value");
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, Alex, it's working. I will investigate why the page is refreshing without rerender="dummy". I noticed that it also works without window.setTimeout() by adding <script>
    setParams("param1Value", "param2Value");
</script> to the bottom of VF page.

Comment: @justasd I've updated my answer with a bit more information on the purpose of the `actionRegion` and `dummy` panel. The page refresh is just a "feature" of using `actionFunction` and is related to Salesforce updating the view state and controller values from the `param` components.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using custom controller then here is how you can do it.

```
<apex:page>
<apex:form>
    ...
    <apex:inputHidden value="{!co.CustomField__c}"/>
    ....
</apex:form>
```

And then write controler

```
public with sharing MyController {

  // Controller code sets this custom object reference
  // When the page is first displayed the CustomField__c value comes from here
  // When the form is submitted, the CustomField__c value is automatically updated
  public CustomObject__c co {get; set;}

  // An action initiated from the Visualforce
  public PageReference save() {
    if (co.Custom_field__c) {
        ....
    }
  }
}
```