# How to pass Client side variable to server side variable?

Tags: javascript

In form I have check box. during runtime i have to get the value of the selected check box in the Page. if i use client side java script means the output will display.

```
<script>
function myFunction()
{
 var checkvalue = document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked;
 if (checkvalue == true) 
 {
 var result = document.getElementById("checkbox1").value;
 }
}
</script>
```

Here i could't access the "result" variable from server side.how to access the client side variable to server side variable?

Comment: This question has incomplete information.you might have to provide more context and possibly a code snapshot.

Comment: Hello Aarthi! Welcome to SFSE. Kindly go through [how-to-ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide. The question doesn't make complete sense, so after reading the guide, provide us with both client side code and server side code.

Comment: <script>
function myFunction()
{
 var checkvalue = document.getElementById("checkbox1").checked;
 if (checkvalue == true) 
 {
 var result = document.getElementById("checkbox1").value;
 }
}
</script>

Comment: I think your solution is right here  - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24666/how-to-pass-javascript-value-to-controller