# How to pass JavaScript array to Apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, javascript, javascript-remoting

Sorry for a simple question. I'm totally new to *Salesforce*.

I want to pass *JavaScript* array to *Apex* to save its data in the *Salesforce* custom object. I want to know the best approach to do it without JavaScript remoting. Following is the *JavaScript* code.

```
$("#saveCalendar").click(function () {
        getDatesBackup = document.getElementById('selectedDates').options;
        for(var k=0; k<getDatesBackup.length; k++){
            allSelectedDates.push(getDatesBackup[k].text);
            console.log("Dates Backup : "+getDatesBackup[k].text);
        }
        console.log(allSelectedDates);
    });
```

Comment: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24666/how-to-pass-javascript-value-to-controller .... May help you....!

Comment: @ShaileshPatil In that question the value is coming from the VF. In my case this is only between JS and Apex. What should be the Apex to retrieve that array from JS?

Comment: You have to define an Apex variable and set the Javascript value to it. How to do that is written in the topic mentioned by @ShaileshPatil

Answer (score 6):

You can use [ActionFunction](http://www.salesforce.com/docs/developer/pages/Content/pages_compref_actionFunction.htm) for this. Here is sample for your reference.

Controller:

```
public class ActionFunctionCLS {

    public void IWantToDebug() {
        list<String> ls = ( List<String> )JSON.deserialize( Apexpages.currentPage().getParameters().get('node'), List<string>.class ) ;        
        System.debug('======================= ' + ls[0] );
        System.debug('======================= ' + ls[1]);
        System.debug('======================= ' + ls[2]);                
    }
}
```

VF Page:

```
    <apex:page controller="ActionFunctionCLS"  >

<script type="text/javascript">
    function doSave(node){
        var arr = ["foo", "bar", "baz"];
        paraFunction(JSON.stringify(arr));
    }       
</script>

<apex:form >
    <apex:actionFunction name="paraFunction" action="{!IWantToDebug}" rerender="view">      
         <apex:param id="anode" name="node" value="" />
   </apex:actionFunction> 
</apex:form>

 <input type="button" onclick="doSave();" value="test" />
```

Note that we are calling `IWantToDebug` Action from JS using `paraFunction` Action Function.

Comment: while useful, it doesn't address OP's requirement of passing a JS array to VF controller

Comment: updated the answer with better example. hope that brings more clarity.

Comment: Excellent!  The JSON.stringify is the key point here as Javascript objects and Apex objects need some common interchange format

Comment: This was very helpful. I had to pass a two dimensional string from Javascript and I just had to change List<String>.class to List<List<String>>.class and it worked fine. Thanks!