# Passing apex var to controller

Tags: apex, visualforce, controller, rerender

```
<apex:form >
  <apex:variable value="{!0.00}" var="total1"/>

  <script>
    document.getElementsByClassName('t1')[0].innerHTML = '{!total1}';
    </script>

          <apex:outputText value="{!z.price}"/>
          <apex:variable var="total1" value="{!total1 + z.price * z.qtyToBuy}"/>
                   <apex:facet name="footer">
                   Total: $<span class="t1"></span>
                   </apex:facet>

                   </apex:column>
```

I have an apex variable total1 declared on my VF page. I would like to pass this total1 var into my apex controller on rerender. How do I pass that?

Thanks guys!

Comment: did you look at 'apex:actionFunction' ?

Comment: @crop1645 could you help me out with this? I've seen the actionFunction. But it's kinda confusing.

Comment: see http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24666/how-to-pass-javascript-value-to-controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a convoluted, but working example:

#### Controller

```
public class passvar {
    public decimal totalValue { get; set; }
    public passvar() {
        totalValue = 5;
    }
}
```

#### Page

```
<apex:page controller="passvar">
    <apex:form id="form">
        <apex:variable value="{!10.00}" var="total"/>
        <button onclick="something({!total}); return false">
            Update Value
        </button>
        <apex:actionFunction reRender="form" name="something">
            <apex:param assignTo="{!totalValue}" value="" name="totalValue"/>
        </apex:actionFunction>
        {!totalValue}: {!total}
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Some notes:

- You need to reRender, or totalValue won't be updated correctly.
- Value attribute on the param is intentionally blank (it's provided by the function).
- Value will be placed inline at the moment the function is rendered. This means it should work correctly inside repeats, etc.

The way you're doing it in your example wouldn't work, because {!total1} will be the value at the time of rendering (i.e. not set from the second value). Your script would have to read the value *after* the second setting of total1. There's probably a better way to do what you're trying to do.