# Visualforce: Pass javascript variable to controller

Tags: visualforce, javascript

I want to pass a javascript variable into the controller of my visualforce page. Using `<apex:param value="JAVASCRIPTVARIABLE" />` is throwing me an error because it expects JAVASCRIPTVARIABLE to be an exposed property of the controller. Please tell me how to pass the value of JAVASCRIPTVARIABLE to a variable in the controller. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can achieve this by using actionFunction.. What have you tried so far?

Comment: @DOMINICEDWARD Achieved this using actionFunction and apex:param . Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a [SFSE link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24666/how-to-pass-javascript-value-to-controller) which talks about how to pass javascript values to controller. It explains how to use `<apex:param` also. Hope this helps.

Snippets

```
<!-- A new value will be set to the apex:param -->
<apex:actionFunction name="passStringToController" action="{!myMethod}" rerender="myHiddenField">
    <apex:param name="p1" value="" assignTo="{!myString}" />
</apex:actionFunction>

<!-- Here we can directly access the action function per name and assign a variable value -->
<apex:commandButton value="Test me" onclick="passStringToController('new value'); return false;" />
```

Comment: @Stygon If it answers your question, please mark it as answer. It will help others.