# passing javascript variable from visual force component to apex controller

Tags: apex, visualforce-component, jquery

how to pass jquery variable from visual force component to apex controller?

The requirement is ,need to validate by checking the storage available in salesforce while uploading files ,

if the files are exceeded the limit need to show feedback message

here the script is in visualforce component

we used dropzone for file uploading

Comment: Refer : http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/24666/how-to-pass-javascript-value-to-controller

Comment: Please post your code so that we can better understand what you are already trying

Answer (score 0):

If your controller is using a @RemoteAction method, you can directly pass whatever params you want when calling that method.
If not, you can declare an `apex:actionFunction` with nested `apex:param` tag, which will become aliased as a JS function that you can simply call from your jQuery code. example:

```
<apex:actionFunction name="myValidator" action="{!yourControllerValidatorMethod}" rerender="">
    <apex:param name="param1" value="" assignTo="{!someControllerProperty}" />
</apex:actionFunction>
```

then in your javascript, you can easily call it like this:  `myValidator(yourJqueryVariable);`